# Extjs confirm box callback handling

Tags: javascript, extjs, callback

In my ExtJs code I am checking the value of a warning flag.

If the flag is set I want to show a confirm (OKCANCEL) box to the user where I ask the user if he wants to proceed even though there is a warning.

Now just like any confirm box if the user clicks OK, the code should proceed to the next command in sequence and if he clicks CANCEL the code should return.

Following is my code:

```
if(warning){
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Icon Support',
        msg: 'Are you sure you want to proceed?',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
        fn: function(btn){
            if(btn == 'ok'){
            // go to the alert statement below.
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    );

    alert('wants to proceed ahead'); //if user clicks OK then come here
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is when the code enters the `if` block it shows the message box and then it alerts `wants to proceed ahead`.

I can stop that from happening by putting a `return;` statement before the `alert()`.

But how do I go to the alert statement after the user clicks OK button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Callbacks it is event driven architecture, and JavaScript it is interpreted programming language.

So the best way will be

```
function SomeFunc(){
//some code 
}
if(warning){
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Icon Support',
        msg: 'Are you sure you want to proceed?',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
        fn: function(btn){
            if(btn == 'ok'){
            SomeFunc();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I know this is possible. But can I avoid doing it? Suppose this confirmation is a new feature/check in an existing code and I just want to insert it in an existing flow. Just check if user is OK with the warning then proceed as earlier else RETURN. No new function creation. Is that possible?

Comment: @DarkKnightFan you can create infinite loop with if that will check some bool variable that will change to true only after OK button will be clicked

Comment: umm... that doesnt sound (feel) too good :( That approach might jeopardize the existing working code

Comment: The only way you can realistically avoid using a callback in this scenario is to use a *real* JavaScript confirmation. The stock confirmation in JS is *blocking*, so it will halt execution of additional scripts until after the user clicks yes or no. The Ext JS confirm is non-blocking (they say as much in the docs), so your code will be finished executing whatever comes after well before the user ever clicks yes or no.

Comment: @DarkKnightFan You cannot avoid. The opening of the message box is asynchronous. As in all things that use asynchroneous processing in Javascript, you cannot get around creating a closure that is called later. You cannot change the way Javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

Something to note, I think your alert may just be an example of code that you are wanting to use as a placeholder for real code processing.

But just in case it's the first line of more code, a plain alert will block the processing of the browser and remove focus from the current window.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

I second Sergey's reply and just had to rearrange code to correctly get callback functions in place, now that a proceed through the message was needed on "Ok". I considered the looping but that was not safe.

Comment: Use console.log() instead of alert(), it is non-intrusive.